# How do I set the "Save draft" button by default on all webform nodes?

Tags: webforms

I have a situation where, when I create a new webform node, its "Save draft" button must be there by default.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_webform_node_defaults_alter().
 */
function mymodule_webform_node_defaults_alter(&$defaults) {
  $defaults['allow_draft'] = '1';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the [Save Draft](http://drupal.org/project/save_draft) module?